# Unix case statement in OSX

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to port some Windows bat files to Mac shell scripts

I get a syntax error when executing a file containing the following case statement:

```
  case ${1} in 
    ( C  | c   ) echo "hoera";;
```

where argument ${1} is given as 'C'

The message is:

```
-bash: even: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'bash: even: line 6: `        ( C  | c   ) echo "hoera";;
```

I think the syntax is correct according to the documentation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on an oldish OS X installation. My suspicion is that the actual error is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you using Bash or `tcsh`? In Bash, that's correct. In Turbo C Shell, it's not. Also make sure that your files have only `<LF`>` as the end of line character and not `<CR><LF>` like Windows files. Sometimes when you see these `unexpected token` things, it's due to someone editing a Windows file. Also please post at least your whole case statement and let us know which line is line 6.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax should be:

```
case $var in
  CASE1) COMMAND-LIST;;
  CASE2) COMMAND-LIST;;
esac
```

Each case consists of one or more [shell patterns](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern), separated by pipes - you don't need an opening parenthesis to match the closing one. Your example should instead be:

```
case ${1} in 
  C|c) echo "hoera";;
```

Or possibly:

```
case ${1} in 
  [Cc]) echo "hoera";;
```

Comment: Or possibly `shopt -s nocasematch; case "${1}" in c) echo "hoera";; …` (Because, coming from Windows, OP is likely to have to do an excessive amount of no-case matching.)

Comment: No, the opening parenthesis is optional, but perfectly permissible. The OP's code is also correct.

Comment: @tripleee except, I think the internal whitespace is not correct... I believe (and some quick testing confirms) that leading/trailing whitespace is stripped from the patterns, but not internal spaces - meaning the OP's pattern is attempting to match either " C  " or " c  ", not just simply "C" or "c"... The actual error quoted by the OP is most likely a line-ending issue unrelated to the case statement...

Comment: My case stunt problem is solved, thanks to the suggestion to remove the <CR>